# How to get data from api each night from the background?

Tags: ios, swift

Hey I am working on an app, each night it should fetch the data from api and depending on the time written there, it should send a local notification at that time. (app for muslim prayers and the time changes every day) Currently I am stack I though about using background mode but the problem is none of those modes seem to provide functionality that I want. For eg. I have read that background fetch fires before the user opens an app to seem it always up to date but what if a user doesn't open an app at all. I still want my users to receive a notification every day (unless the user disables notifications himself). I searched but it seems like impossible. Can someone please help what should I do? Or should I click that I am going to track user's location but send requests to api instead? I am afraid that apple is going to reject my app then. :( Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you can send a push notification everynight. The maximum payload for APNs is 2kB so maybe if you can fit the data you want to send through the APi into the push notification itself. Then it would work as expected.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Executing tasks in the background is indeed possible (and no, of course Apple won't reject your app for using it). You can check out background fetch. From the official docs: "Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for that content.". Read more here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: You can use silent push notification or background task to call API from background. However, these are not trusted one.  OS will decide when to call the delegate methods based on uses of App, battery available etc.